# Salesforce Custom Objects

Tags: plugins

Is there a simple way to integrate CraftCMS with Salesforce Custom Objects? I have looked at the available plugins which seem to cater for leades and opportunities but I need custom objects.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't find an existing plugin that does Salesforce Custom Objects integrations, then you're looking at writing some custom code to do it (whether that's a private plugin/module for your specific needs or something you release publicly on the [Plugin Store](https://plugins.craftcms.com).